# How to use Rebus in combination with OracleDB

Tags: oracle, asp.net-core, rebus

I am trying to make Rebus work on Oracle DB but I keep getting errors.
I have the following configuration in my Startup:
In the ConfigureServices

```
        services.AutoRegisterHandlersFromAssemblyOf<NewActionRequestMessageHandler>();
        services.AddRebus(configure => configure
                .Logging(l => l.Serilog())
                .Transport(t => t.UseOracle(connectionString, "QueueTable", "Queue"))
                .Routing(r => r.TypeBased()
                    .Map<NewActionRequestMessage>("Queue")
                    .Map<RevokeActionRequestMessage>("Queue"))
                .Subscriptions(s => s.StoreInOracle(connectionString, "Subscriptions")));
```

In the Configure

```
        var bus = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IBus>();
        app.ApplicationServices.UseRebus();

        bus.Send(new NewActionRequestMessage());
```

The error I get is:

> [11:55:48] Alpha event ID:  Partition ID:  - An error occurred when attempting to receive the next message: "Rebus.Exceptions.RebusApplicationException: Could not 'GetOrAdd' item with key 'oracle-transport-connection' as type Rebus.Oracle.UnitOfWork
> ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Rebus.Transport.ITransactionContext.OnCommitted(System.Func`1<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>)'. at Rebus.Oracle.Transport.TransactionContextExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<GetConnection>b__0() at Rebus.Transport.TransactionContextExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass2_0`1.b__0(String id)
> at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
> at Rebus.Transport.TransactionContextExtensions.GetOrAdd[TItem](ITransactionContext context, String key, Func`1 newItemFactory) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Rebus.Transport.TransactionContextExtensions.GetOrAdd[TItem](ITransactionContext context, String key, Func`1 newItemFactory)
> at Rebus.Oracle.Transport.TransactionContextExtensions.GetConnection(ITransactionContext context, OracleFactory factory)
> at Rebus.Oracle.Transport.OracleTransport.Receive(ITransactionContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Rebus.Workers.ThreadPoolBased.ThreadPoolWorker.ReceiveTransportMessage(CancellationToken token, ITransactionContext context)"

Help?

Comment: You got the error because Rebus.Oracle had not been updated to Rebus 6.

It has been updated now, and it's out as Rebus.Oracle 2.0.0 on NuGet.org now. 

Comment: Btw if I were you, I would configure subscriptions to be "centralized" by adding `isCentralized: true` in the subscriptions configuration - this will configure subscribers to register themselves directly in the subscriptions database, which means that the entire routing configuration for events can be skipped 